# php form submit in div fails

Tags: php, html, submit

after many days of trying to get a previously working php form converted to submitting the variables inside a new div I realized that I'm missing something. Other posts show javascript, but Iv'e never used that before and don't understand the need. The new page draws correctly, but the php variables are not being received on the destination page.

HTML for the submit,

```
<form action="entrance2.php">
<div class="medium-12 columns m-b20"><h4 class="heading">Existing users log-in here :-</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
<div class="user medium-12 columns text-center m-b15"><img src="images/user-img.png" alt=""/></div>
</div>  
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-10 columns medium-offset-1"><label for="User Name"></label>
<input id="OwnerEmaili" type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="UserName"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-10 columns medium-offset-1"><label for="Password"></label>
<input id="OwnerPasswordi" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 columns  text-center"><button class="grd-button">Log In</button></div>
<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value = "Submit"/>//simple submit for testing
<div class="grd-button1" onClick="document.forms['submit-form'].submit();"></div>
</form></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Receiving page,

```
<?php
$p_OwnerEmaili=$_POST["OwnerEmaili"];
$p_OwnerPasswordi=$_POST["OwnerPasswordi"];

echo "$p_OwnerEmaili;$p_OwnerPasswordi";
```

Only shows the ;.

Is javascript required to submit from inside a div?

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing the wrong items.

You'll need to set your forms input `name` attributes to this if you want to access them the way you currently have in your php script:

```
<input id="OwnerEmaili" type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="OwnerEmaili">
```

And

```
<input id="OwnerPasswordi" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="OwnerPasswordi">
```

That will allow you to access them as you do in your PHP script.

You can always check what values have been sent to your php script by using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

<sup>*Would've shown you that you had `UserName` & `Password` set instead of what you wanted.*</sup>

---

As Ghost pointed out in the comments, your form will **always** send user input via `GET` if you dont specify a `method` in it. So set this in your `form` tag:

```
<form action="entrance2.php" method="post">
```

Comment: also tell the OP that `forms` default to `GET` when not specified